# zabbix 500 error web scenario - log requests

Tags: zabbix

I have a multi-step web scenario, but one of the steps is producing a 500 error.  It's JSON POST step, using variables from a previous step, so plenty of opportunity for things to go wrong.  I don't see any way to diagnose what exactly is happening however.

Is there any way for Zabbix to either record the cURL requests it is making, or log the result if it is a 500 Error?  I'm running the latest 3.2 code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot log requests with Zabbix. If it is an HTTP request, a simple `tcpdump` might help with that, though.

As for responses, you can make Zabbix log web scenario responses by increasing loglevel to `5`. This can also be done for a running server and only for the web scenario processes like this:
`zabbix_server -R log_level_increase http\ poller`

See [this blog entry](http://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-2-4-features-part-6-runtime-loglevel-changing/3653/) for more detail.